# Is there a way to add custom aspect ratios in the image editor?

Tags: image, editor

We'd like to add a custom aspect ratio to the list of aspect aspect ratios in the image editor so our client doesn't have to look it up to remember each time. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be possible using a new `imageEditorRatios` [config setting](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html) that is coming in Craft 3.5 (due to release in early August 2020):

```php
...
'imageEditorRatios' => [
    'Unconstrained' => 'none',
    'Original' => 'original',
    'Square' => 1,
    '16:9' => 1.78,
    '10:8' => 1.25,
    '7:5' => 1.4,
    '4:3' => 1.33,
    '5:3' => 1.67,
    '3:2' => 1.5,
    'Some custom ratio' => 1.9,
];
```

[Source (GitHub issue)](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/6201#issuecomment-647106804)